# Django 1.2 object level permissions - third party solutions?

Tags: python, django, permissions

Since Django 1.2 final is almost out, I am curious if there are already projects that use the new object level permissions / row level permissions system. [Django-authority](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/), which is a possible solution for Django up to 1.1, has not been updated for a while, and does not (yet) use the new permissions system. It seems to me that [Django-Authority](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/) is in a comatose state.

Does someone know about upcoming or maybe even finished solutions? I'd appreciate any good links to active projects with at least some downloadable content very much.

Comment: Found one more nice solution: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian - seems to also work with Django 1.3!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found really good stuff: Florian Apolloner wrote a howto on djangoadvent: http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/object-permissions/
Now **that's** what I'm gonna use :)

Something useful might be as well: http://github.com/washingtontimes/django-objectpermissions (link dead as of 2011-07-18)

Comment: I read Florian's post, and while it is informative, it does not appear to support group permissions. For example, if a group is given permission to an object (is that even supported in Florian's example?), will users in that group have permission to the object?

Comment: for my project i did not need group permissions. in any case, you'll have to implement it yourself. but maybe there is already an other django app out there - I didn't check for some months.

Answer (score 9):

I used https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian when it was still in version 0.2 on a project and it was rather complete and bug free.

Yes I did have to write my own 'check_permission' view decorator as at the time it didn't have it included yet - but at least from version 1.0 it is there.

The author was also very quick to respond to an issue I had migrating from 0.2 - overall I've been happy with it and hence made it part of my project skeleton template.

Answer (score 5):

I have released a Django-app called [django-rules](https://github.com/maraujop/django-rules) which lets you manage per object permissions in a flexible, dynamic and scalable way. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [django-granular-permissions](http://code.google.com/p/django-granular-permissions/) for a site a while ago, but was unable to get it to do what I needed (this may have been my own inability to understand what I needed to do rather than the app). Looking at the google code site's updates tab, it looks to not have had any work done on it since Summer/Autumn last year so it may be another dead duck.

Comment: also, the project seems to have moved: http://github.com/ryates/django-granular-permissions-redux

Answer (score 1):

OSU Open Source Labs has an implementation of object level permissions [here](http://code.osuosl.org/projects/object-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the main source of information is [djangopackages.com's perms grid](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/): "A grid of all packages implementing permissions for users and groups in your Django project". (Beware some packages are named very similarly, e.g. an 's' or a dash is the only difference)

Then, reviewing each package features (considering only the somewhat-actively maintained subset), these are the main candidates:

- **django-guardian**: “implementation of per object permissions as authorization backend which is supported since Django 1.2.”
  [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-authority), [repo](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-guardian), [docs](http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/).
- **django-permissions**: “Generic per-object permissions for Django”. “django-permissions provides per-object permissions for Django on roles”.
  [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-permissions), [original repo](https://bitbucket.org/diefenbach/django_permissions/), [most updated fork](https://bitbucket.org/schacki/django-permissions/), [docs](http://packages.python.org/django-permissions/).
- **django-authority**: “provides generic per-object-permissions for Django's auth app.” “Django app for per-object-permissions that includes a bunch of helpers to create custom permission checks.”
  [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-authority), [original repo](https://bitbucket.org/jezdez/django-authority/), [most updated fork](https://bitbucket.org/evotech/django-authority/), [docs](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/).

There are others that for one reason or the other did not make the cut:

- [django-object-permissions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-object-permissions)
- [django-rulez](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rulez)
- [django-permission](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-permission)

PS: This answer was written according to the current state of open source packages, more than 2 years after the question was asked. Although not too thorough, I hope this work will help those that are in the same situation I was.