# Update UserGroup management with Django

Tags: django, permissions

We have a implementation problem with users, groups and organisations.
Our situation:

- We have organisations.
- In an organisation we have some users.
- Each user has permissions based on his group (admin, user, read-only).

Now, we need to manage users permissions through organisations.

User 1 can be admin in organisation1 and read-only into organisation2

How can we do ? Can we update the built-in user group management or do we have to create a new relation table ?

Comment: Hi! Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037402/django-permissions-code-ourselves-or-use-app/8037471#8037471).